# How to name column from table gotten with sys.odcinumberlist

Tags: sql, oracle

The column name of this query

```
Select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(3,4,3))
```

is named column_value.

I would like to rename the column

This solution works but it complicate unnecessarity the code. Is there a better way to that?

```
select t.column_value myNumber from (Select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(3,4,3)) ) t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle's `table` syntax does generate an anonymous table, with a unique column called `column_value`. You don't need a subquery to do what you want, you can directly alias the column in the `select` clause:

```
select column_value myNumber from table(sys.odcinumberlist(3,4,3))
```